# Why didn't Euclid use equations or numerals in his proofs?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, euclidean-geometry

I think the *Elements* would have been a lot more concise if he did.

Comment: Probably similar to the reason that none of my high school teachers used sticky notes to mark certain pages of their teacher edition textbooks, but many teachers did so after around 1980 or 1981.

Comment: Euclid wrote in a rhetorical manner simply because symbolic expressions had not yet been developed.  I believe that this remained the case until renaissance Europe.  The Greeks sometimes used the letters of the alphabet as numerals in a manner similar to the ancient Hebrew method - a decimal, non-positional system which used the first nine letters of the alphabet to represent the numbers 1 to 9.  Numbers were sometimes written with a bar or dot over the letter in order to distinguish numbers from words. Various superscripts were used to write "large" numbers.

Comment: Because he did not take an undergraduate course of Analytic geometry.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I wasn't referring to analytic geometry at all. One can use equations and numerals in Euclidean geometry as well. For example, Euclid would write "angles ABC and XYZ equal two right angles" instead of "$\angle ABC+\angle XYZ=180^0$".

Comment: Euclid did not use degrees, of course. (Can you explain what's a degree, in a simple way and with Euclidean rigor? Without Calculus, which Euclid did not now.) Concerning $\angle ABC$ vs "angle ABC", there is really no much difference.

Comment: The notions of "angle of x degrees" or "x radians", where x is a  number DO NOT belongs to Geometry, and Euclid understood this, unlike most modern students. These things belong to Calculus. If you want to see a proof of this, look into the book by Dieudonne, Linear Algebra and Geometry,  https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Geometry-Jean-Dieudonne/dp/B000NOVO0S

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. But Ptolemy (and his sources) did use degrees, without knowledge of calculus,

Comment: @fdb: Ptolemy was an applied mathematician. He was concerned with numerical approximations. Babylonians also used degree. But they had no concept of rigorous mathematics. While Euclid's Elements is pure mathematics, with rigorous proofs.

Comment: @Nick. Two corrections: Diophantus used algebraic symbols, long before the Renaissance. Second: the "ancient Hebrew" use of letters of the alphabet for numbers (which is not used anywhere in the Bible) was borrowed from the Greeks in the Hellenistic period. It is a Greek invention. It was used not "sometimes" but regularly in mathematical and astronomical works. And it is "positional" according to the sexagesimal system.

Comment: @fdb In both cases I am paraphrasing Leo Corry's recent text *A Brief History of Numbers*, which I highly recommend.  It is possible that the Greeks and Hebrews developed their system independently.  Regarding Diophantus (and Brahmagupta, et al) I believe that Corry's view is the standard view here.

Comment: @fdb Hi.  Re-reading my initial comment I see it is poorly worded. Diophantus and others did indeed use symbols expressions.  However, they were largely difficult to work with and lacking in the necessary generality to qualify as mathematically advantageous symbolic expressions.

Comment: @fdb I have had an opportunity to review Corry's text (over my lunch) and he does not say that the Greeks "borrowed" this notation from the Hebrew form, only that they were similar.  However, in terms of chronology, he does introduce the Hebrew notation before that of the Greeks.  I suspect that you are correct here, and that they were roughly contemporaneous though it is not clear that either influenced the other.